# Homemade sport drink

Tags: drinks, recipe-scaling

I'm trying to develop a recipe for homemade sport drink as Gaterade and the like contains unhealthy and/or unnecessary ingredients that I dislike.  I found a base recipe I'd like to work with to variate and tweak: http://wellnessmama.com/2575/natural-sports-drink/ .  Is there any obvious aspects in this recipe that need modification and/or can be improved?  One particular question is if the tea liquid will be chemically reactive to the calcium tablets and be health-wise unviable?  The goal is to make the drink all at home and let it be healthy and well suited for drinking during performing sports.

Comment: Can you be more specific? This is a food and cooking site, not a nutritional site, so if you're asking about nutritional benefits that's off topic. And if you're asking how to make it taste better, that's pretty subjective and wide-open, and we don't take questions like that either.

Comment: Where's the potassium coming from in that recipe? Gatorade requires 14g sugar, 110mg sodium and 30mg potassium per 8 oz: http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-Your-Own-Damn-Sports-Drink/step2/Whats-in-a-sports-drink/ -No Calcium need apply. I just make up a 20X stock of the two salts, then mix 150 ml up w a pack of Koolaid (any flavor) and water to 3 quarts. Tot of 1/4 cup Sugar, or Stevia as desired to make it more palatable.

Comment: I put your question on hold, because it isn't clear what you want to change in the drink (or not change). As the question stands, it already had attracted a nutrition based topic. If you edit the question to tell us what you are trying to achieve, and it is a culinary (not nutritional) goal, we can reopen so you can get answers about tweaking the recipe.

Comment: Detaching nutrition from cooking seems hard.  But I'll try.

Comment: In many cases, detaching nutrition from cooking is not hard. But I think that the problem here is that your question is in its core a nutrition question and not a cooking one. You want to know what makes your drink healthy, and taste is a secondary consideration. But we cannot tell you what makes the drink healthy, and therefore it is off topic for the site :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This recipe is essentially sugar and salt added to a "normal drink," so the rest of the recipe ought to be fine assuming good quality ingredients.

Comment: Sorry, but we have a policy to not discuss nutrition here. Your ideas about calcium absorption might be correct, but they are off topic, so I have to remove that part of the answer. The simplest rule is: if it is about human physiology, it is off topic.